# Unique HASHID with 20 characters limit using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, hashbytes

A code has a 20 character limit but it needs to be unique. To make it unique there are 3 parts combinations of these values will exceed the 20 characters limits, more like 40 – 50 size. So the idea is to generate some type of unique ID based on that string, but does not exceed 20 characters.

I was exploring the possible use of SQL Server `Hashbytes` function which put everything into hash and make it smaller (examples below).

However, all of the old 16 bit/32 bit hash function has been retired by Microsoft, and the newer ones which a lot more accurate will have something around 30 – 40 characters. Which defeats the purpose.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought...

On option is to convert the `hashbytes()` to a `bigint`.

**Example**

```
Declare @Table table (Col1 varchar(25),Col2 varchar(25),Col3 int)
Insert into @Table values
('V5H 3K3','AAA',25),
('V6L 4L4','VVV',16),
('V4E 5L2','CCC',25),
('V5H 3K3','AAA',27)

Select *
      ,UniID = left(abs(convert(bigint,HashBytes('MD5', concat(col1,col2,col3)))),20)
 From  @Table
```

**Results**

```
Col1        Col2    Col3    UniID
V5H 3K3     AAA     25      8561734070678522554
V6L 4L4     VVV     16      2225152452607129855
V4E 5L2     CCC     25      5842957356638096832
V5H 3K3     AAA     27      1688308399631225138
```

Comment: This isn't intended to be adversarial, but how does that solve the OP's problem of using only supported hashing algorithms? You're still using MD5, regardless of the cast to bigint.

Comment: @BenThul At the end of the day, OP needed a unique id limited to 20 characters based off of 3 columns.  Considering the result is BIGINT, SHA2_256/512 doesn't buy you anything.  Odds of a collision are astronomical.

Comment: Let me rephrase the question - the OP specifically stated "all of the old 16 bit/32 bit hash function has been retired by Microsoft" as a concern. MD5 is one the deprecated algorithms. I agree with you in re: collision likelihood. That said, why cast to bigint at all? Using MD5 already returns 16 bytes which already meets the spec. One might argue that bytes <> characters, but that's a red herring to me. Just because MD5 is normally formatted as hexadecimal characters doesn't mean that's the only way to encode it.

Comment: @BenThul Simple example more than 16 bytes.   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=fc9f08c9b0b1268817faf36e8af18ac3   Again, just an option to satisfy a rather constrictive requirement.

Comment: I think you're using "more than 16 hexadecimal digits" to mean "more than 16 bytes". https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=f283b8dea2aad623f292a6b3894d30c1. Even with my augmentation to your code though, I wouldn't store this as `varchar` or `nvarchar` - store it as `binary(16)` because that's what hashbytes is producing.

Comment: @BenThul You are correct, I misread 16 bytes for 16 characters.   I also assumed OP was locked into 20 character/human readable solution.   That said, I appreciate your insights.